# Using jQuery to search for data attributes

Tags: jquery

I have a select field which contains the following options:

```
 <select class="course_date_selector applicationSelec">
      <option location="Port Moresby" value="300" style="display:none;" course="285-Port Moresby">Aug-01-2015 </option>
      <option location="Port Moresby" value="200" style="display:none;" course="285-Port Moresby">Aug-05-2015 </option>
      <option location="Location B" value="200" style="display:none;" course="285-Location B">Aug-29-2015 </option>
      <option location="Port Moresby" value="230" style="display:none;" course="284-Port Moresby">Aug-06-2015 </option>
 </select>
```

Using jQuery, how can show all options where the the course attribute is equal to 285-Location B?

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
$(function(){
  $('.course_date_selector option[course="285-Location B"]').show();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j8Lnt8w4/18/)